# Why can't I access my authorized page after using jwt nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, postman

I used jwt to authorize my user login page and it worked perfectly when I tested using postman but when I try to create a page that should be accessible to only authorized users, it doesn't work. I don't know why it doesn't authorize users. PS:When I login, I get a random token and I copy it then go to the route that should be authorized and I select Ithe bearer token option in postman to test

//THIS IS MY AUTH.JS FILE

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  // try {
    //   get the token from the authorization header
    // const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    res.status(401).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'Unauthorized!',
      });
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, 'RANDOM-TOKEN');
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'Unauthorized!',
      });
  }
}
```

// AND THIS IS MY INDEX.JS FILE

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// require mongoDb file from the db folder
const dbConnect = require("./db/mongoDB");

// require Users from the UserModel Schema File
const User = require("./db/userModel");

//require auth from the Auth file
const auth = require("./auth");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// body parser configuration
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

dbConnect();

// Curb Cores Error by adding a header here
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send({message: "Hello World!"});
});

app.get("/auth-endpoint", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "You are authorized to access me" });
});

// Post request to hash password using bcrypt and save user details to database
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then((hashedPassword) => {
        const user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            matric_number: req.body.matric_number
        });
        user.save()
          .then((result) => {
            res.status(201).send({
              message: "User Created Successfully",
              result,
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Error creating user",
              error,
            });
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Password was not succesfully hashed, ${e}`
        });
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ matric_number: req.body.matric_number })
  .then((user) => {
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    .then((passwordCheck) => {
      // check if password matches
      if(!passwordCheck) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Passwords does not match", error, });
      }
      //create JWT Token
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          userId: user._id,
          userMatricNumber: user.matric_number
        },
        "RANDOM_TOKEN",
        { expiresIn: "24h" }
      );
      //   return success response
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Login Successful",
        matric_number: user.matric_number,
        token,
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send({ message: `Passwords don't match, ${e}` });
    })
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.status(404).send({ message: `Login Error, ${e}` });
  });
});

// free endpoint
app.get("/free-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "You are free to access me anytime" });
});

// authentication endpoint
app.get("/auth-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "You are authorized to access me" });
});

//Run the backend on localhost port 5000
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port 5000`);
});
```